# How can you disable Metro when running a React Native app via Xcode?

Tags: react-native

I think there's some networking issues with my Mac (my workplace has an over the top amount of mandatory software installed like anti malware, vpns, bad website policing stuff installed) that I think is interfering with the virtual network stuff going on between the Mac and the iPhone.
Anyway, it takes about 5 minutes for an app to launch and Metro get set up, that's painfully too slow. If the app is installed from TestFlight it launches instantly. Also I get cannot connect to Metro error sometimes as well.

I want to be able to exclude Metro from getting involved when running via Xcode.
I used to have this working in the past by having the following script in Xcode's build phases to copy the jsbundle to the phone.

yes | cp -rf ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/main.jsbundle $SRCROOT/main.jsbundle

But it stopped working some time ago after a React Native version bump.

How can I get this working again? i.e. get installations/running via Xcode to launch instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this would be painful as well since, if you don't have metro running each single change you make in the javascript code base, won't be automatically refresh to the device.

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file ./index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

This command will make js bundle and if metro is not connected the iOS Simulator will take this js bundle as main one.

Again you will have to run this command even if you change a 'string' in your js code otherwise it won't reflect the change.